# Dynamodb write and fetch old row

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement where when I update in a row with primarykey and sortkey - I need to fetch all old rows with same primary key back. Can this be done in single request. Note:say my primary key is userid and sort key is activity type. When I update a row corresponding to one activitytype for a user , I need to fetch all rows of that user with all activity types. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

TD;DR **no**

The longer answer is this is not supported by DynamoDB. You can't even always get all items for the same sort key in one request (*it's only possible when the number of items is relatively small and the items themselves are not too big*), much less issue a single request to update an item *and* execute a query with potentially many result *pages*, all in one go.

The underlying answer to your unasked question is DynamoDB doesn't support transactions (multiple operations executed atomically, without interference from other operations).